# What's on the bottom of the Shuttle's external fuel tank?

Tags: space-shuttle, identify-this-object, external-tank

In the Wikipedia article about [Spaceplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceplane) there's a (rare and cool) shot of the Space Shuttle from one of the SBRs immediately after it was released. The [web page for the image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SRBsepfromDiscovery07042006.png) says:

> Space Shuttle Discovery seen with her external fuel tank as she climbs into orbit 3 seconds after solid rocket booster separation on STS-121, July 4, 2006. Photo from video from the right aft SRB camera.

It looks like there are three circular areas at the "bottom" end of the tank. Two appear bright and reflective (and overlap) and a third appears dark.

What are these areas called and what are their functions?

[image]

Comment: When I was working on shuttle main propulsion system simulation long, long before the 107 disaster, I always wanted a good photo of STS in 2nd stage, when just the SSMEs are running and those distracting SRBs are gone. Never really thought it would happen though.  Not to mention video!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is an access hatch used during construction and maintenance.

[image]
**Credit: NASA-KSC**

[image]
**Credit: NASA**

---

This part got at least some media coverage during the scrubbing of STS-121, when a Engine Cutoff (ECO) sensor, a fuel gauge, mounted behind that cover, inside the Liquid Hydrogen (LH2) tank, malfunctioned, causing that launch to be delayed, while the sensors were replaced. This is where the first image is from.

[Here](https://www.spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts121/060511ecoreplace/) and [here](https://www.space.com/4564-fuel-sensor-glitch-prevents-space-shuttle-launch.html) are articles about the scrub.

[image]
**Credit: NASA**

---

Some of those hatches/holes are covered with the insulation foam during manufacturing.

[image]
**Credit: [Lawrence Tsuei](https://www.insideedison.com/stories/space-shuttle-fuel-tank-et-94-arrives-at-its-new-home)**

---

Some pictures of a test article that are probably not representative of the actual tank but illustrate the covers quite nicely, that are underneath the insulation foam.

[image]
**Credit: [Project Habu (with more images)](http://projecthabu.com/post/97856002358/the-space-shuttle-external-tank-can-be-broken)**

Comment: Wow, very informative, and colorful answer!

Comment: Ah, yeah. Apparently a common solution for tanks that need to be welded from inside in case you don't intend to use the lost welder method.

Comment: That picture from "project habu" is not representative of the aft end of a flight LH2 tank.  It's an early ground test article. What you show *may*  be similar to the forward dome end of a flight LH2 tank, but it isn't the aft dome of one for sure.  That said, that's a really cool web site, thanks for the link.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that explains why it confused me.  Though, is it just me that thinks it looks like an R2 unit that's fallen over?

Comment: TLDR: the tank has three belly buttons.

Answer (score 22):

This part of the External Tank is called the "LH<sub>2</sub> Tank aft dome". There are really two large circular penetrations on it. They are the ones offset from the center of the tank.

One is the access hatch/manhole. (this description is from the LO<sub>2</sub> tank part of the linked document. Further down it says the LH<sub>2</sub> "manhole fitting was similar to those on both the LO<sub>2</sub> tank domes and the LH<sub>2</sub> tank forward dome")

> A 45”-diameter manhole fitting, welded to the dome  cap, provided a
>   36”-diameter clear access to  the  tank  interior.  The  fitting 
>   featured  ninety-two  attachment  points  for  mating  to  the 
>   machined   aluminum  manhole  cover.  The  fifty-seven  pound 
>   manhole  cover  measured  40.32”  in  overall   diameter  and  0.185” 
>   thick  at  the   center.  It  provided  an  interfacing  sealing 
>   surface  with  the   manhole fitting, as well as a means for making a
>   leak check of the primary seal.

The other is the "siphon plate hole".  It's where this large device is mounted and was inserted during manufacture.

Here is an inside view of the aft part of the LH<sub>2</sub> tank, manhole at the bottom, siphon at the top.

[image]

The 3rd circular feature in the center is an artifact of the manufacturing process and of the way the insulating foam was applied.

Here is a picture I took of an ET on the launch pad, stacked for flight.  The manhole is at the top and the siphon plate is at the bottom.

[image]

Sources: [HAER report](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/4.pdf), personal photo, [External Tank - legacy of success](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20120001570.pdf)

**BONUS** Something to think about: Why wasn't the siphon in the geometric center of the tank bottom?  Mouseover for answer.

> Because of the side mounting of the tank to the Orbiter with the engines mounted on the Orbiter, the acceleration vector was tilted away from the centerline of the tank.

Comment: Thanks! So the "siphon plate hole" might be used only during initial assembly, and the access hatch is likely the only thing used regularly, at least on this end?

Comment: I'd have to look but I think the manhole was also for assembly.  The tank was shipped from Michoud all foamed up and ready to shoot; if they had to access the inside of the LH2 tank after shipping it would have been a big deal.

Comment: In this image https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/105045main_et-3-lg.jpg you can see a tank arriving and it's already all sealed up.

Comment: I'm guessing the different coloured bit closer to axis is from a rotisserie style coating process?

Comment: I think so, and the spot in the center when the "axle" attached was later foamed manually.